# How to use Flash BitmapData to scale up a image without losing the quality?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I'm trying scale up an image in Flash without making it pixelated, I know that I will loose some quality
by scaling up, but i'm not trying to scale 6 times bigger or something :)

I tried to use matrix and scale, but the quality is just bad... is there any other ways to do this?

---

so here's my code,

```
var _bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0x00000000 );
var _scale:Number = Math.max(stage.stageWidth/_imageLoad.contentAsBitmap.width, stage.stageHeight/_imageLoad.contentAsBitmap.height)
var _matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
_matrix.scale(_scale, _scale);

_bmpData.draw( _imageLoad.contentAsBitmap, _matrix, null, null, null, true);

var _bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap( _bmpData, 'always', true );
```

The thing is that if I dont use matrix, everything's fine and not pixelated, but if I use matrix to scale, it's pixelated.... is there any way to fix this? thanks

Comment: You completely changed the context of the question. You should accept an answer and ask a more specific question regarding scaling matrices and pixelation in AS3. Either that, or edit the title of this one to reflect the new more specific question (but that negates the answers to your previous edits).

Comment: You probably don't even need a bitmapdata... if you are loading the image with loader, you can do this:
Bitmap(loader.content).smoothing=true;
for more cae scenarios check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058187/rotation-in-flash-causing-image-borders-to-look-pixely-how-to-fix/1058312#1058312

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myBitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
myBitmap.smoothing = true;
```

You can also look at the draw method of the BitmapData class, which has a smoothing parameter. Obviously this isn't going to help with the inherent issues of upresing an image, but it might mitigate them slightly.